# Windows Docker-Compose Not Connecting to Wordpress Database

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-volume

I have a mysql database and wp-content folder from the site I am working on. My OS is Windows 10. These are the current settings I'm using in the docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
volumes:
    db_data: {}
```

When removing the following line, the database loads

```
     volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
```